# SpringBoot 1.5.3 createStoredProcedureQuery not accepting Null parameters

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, stored-procedures

While using SpringBoot with MSSQL server stored proc, when the value is null, Stored proc fails to execute. the value have default as null while calling.
If the parameters are excluded, the proc works. But as these are optional parameters, what are my options to call the stored proc?

When i try to pass null while calling the stored procedure, it is failing with this error.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults; SQL [saveInfo]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter #1 has not been set.
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.executeSQL(TdsCore.java:1049)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:563)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.execute(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:787)
        at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.<init>(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:32)
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:411)
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:363)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.outputs(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:217)
        at com.tda.etfmc.service.repository.ETFMgmtRepository.saveCommissionFreeETF(ETFMgmtRepository.java:87)
        at com.tda.etfmc.service.repository.ETFMgmtRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d1d68142.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
```

StoredProc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[saveInfo]  
     @input1                        varchar(16) = NULL,
     @input2                        varchar(16) = NULL
AS  
BEGIN   
//do save here
END  

GO


@Repository
public class MyRepository {
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public MyRepository(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Procedure(name = "saveInfo")
    @Transactional
    public void saveInfo(List<Input> inputList) throws SQLException {
        StoredProcedureQuery saveInfo;
        for (Input input : inputList) {
            saveInfo = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("saveInfo");
            saveInfo.setParameter("input1", input.getInput1());// pass null here
            saveInfo.setParameter("input2", input.getInput2());
            saveInfo.execute();
        }
    }
}

@Data
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "saveInfo", procedureName = "saveInfo", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "input1", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "input2", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN) })
class Input implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "@input1")
    private String input1;

    @Column(name = "@input2")
    private String input2;
}
```

Comment: Could you check the value before committing to the transaction and then rather than passing null pass an empty string. Then in the stored procedure deal with the empty string.?

Comment: I expect null value to be stored, as empty string indicates user has provided some value. Also, i have other scenario where i have to store some decimals. i cannot store '0' as it is a valid value too.